# Extract row with a particular scenario

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with following details

```
EMP_NAME     TEST_RESULT   RUN_DATE
----------------------------------------------
John            Pass    12-FEB-2013 18:03:55
Albert          Fail    12-FEB-2013 18:24:29
Chris           Pass    12-FEB-2013 18:24:28
John            Fail    12-FEB-2013 19:32:35
Chris           Pass    12-FEB-2013 19:32:35
Steve           Pass    12-FEB-2013 20:04:35
```

Now I need to extract row with unique names AND TEST_RESULT. But the test result should have only "Fail" result if employee has both pass and fail results. The result of the query should be

```
EMP_NAME     TEST_RESULT   RUN_DATE
----------------------------------------------
Albert          Fail    12-FEB-2013 18:24:29
Chris           Pass    12-FEB-2013 18:24:28
John            Fail    12-FEB-2013 19:32:35
Steve           Pass    12-FEB-2013 20:04:35
```

All I care about is only one EMPLOYEE NAME and if there are two results pass and fail for that EMPLOYEE, show me only FAIL record and I don't care about the time. If there are two results for an EMPLOYEE as "pass" and "pass" I still need one record and i don't care about the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select emp_name, test_result, run_date 

 from (

select emp_name, test_result, run_date, 

 row_number() over (partition by emp_name 
 order by test_result, run_date ) rn

 from

T1)

where rn=1`

Comment: +1 but for the benefit of future seekers: this particular solution works because `'FAIL' < 'PASS'` is true.  It will need tweaking if the desired sort criteria is not in alphabetical order.

Comment: Also, the additional sort by RUN_DATE is strictly unnecessary for the OP because "i don't care about the time" but necessary for the rest of us who do appreciate reproducibility.

Comment: If order would need to be different, that would just make change in order by. Concerning run_date, it was added to match given example - sure if needed, it can ce removed...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work.

```
select emp_name, test_result, run_date
from YourTable
where test_result = 'Fail'
union
select emp_name, test_result, run_date
from YourTable
where test_result = 'Pass'
and emp_name in 
(select emp_name
from YourTable
where TestResult = 'Pass'
minus
select emp_name
from YourTable 
where TestResult = 'Fail'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EMP_NAME, TEST_RESULT, RUN_DATE
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.EMP_NAME ORDER BY RUN_DATE) AS RowNumber,
       t1.EMP_NAME, TEST_RESULT, RUN_DATE
  FROM MyTable t1
  LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT EMP_NAME 
   FROM MyTable
   WHERE TEST_RESULT = 'Fail' 
  ) AS EMP_With_Failure ON t1.EMP_NAME = EMP_With_Failure.EMP_Name
  WHERE t1.TEST_RESULT = 'Fail' OR EMP_With_Failure.EMP_NAME IS NULL ) t
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

This query will filter out any Success record for any user that have a failure, you still need to filter the result set to get only one record per user

Comment: I'm pretty sure,that if you ran this query on the data in the question, it will return John twice.

Comment: @DanBracuk you are correct, I am not returning one row per user because the OP didn't specify which record should be returned when multiple are present, it should not be a challenge though!

Comment: @DanBracuk And your query will return Chris twice :)

Comment: @DanBracuk I added a simple RowNumber wrapper around it, should be all good now :)

Comment: @ypercube, my query will indeed return Chris twice.  That's because the run_dates are different and the OP did not say what to do in that situation.  Hopefully he reads this comment and adds to his question,

Comment: @all.. I read your comments.. interesting.. All I care about is only one EMPLOYEE NAME and if there are two results for pass and fail, show me only FAIL record and I don't care about the time. If there are two results for an EMPLOYEE  as "pass" and "pass" I still need one record and i don't care about the time.

Comment: @BassamMehanni : When I run the query it says "missing keyword"... pls help